# Testing account existence using expect

Tags: bash, expect, send

I have a list of 400 servers and I like to check unix account existence with expect to loop it

I wrote a bash script that uses expect command but it returns me error message that I don't understand the meaning

```
#!/bin/bash
fic_serv="test.txt"
echo "Passwd"
stty -echo
read -s passwd
stty echo
suffix="suffix"
account="acc"


for server in `cat $fic_serv`
do
        prompt="[$acc@$server ~]$ "
        expect -c "
        spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $account@$server.$suffix
        expect  "Password: "
        send "$passwd\r"
        expect $prompt
        send "logout\r"
        "
done


[acc@serv ~]$ couldn't read file "
        send "passwd\r"
        expect [acc@server ~]$
        send "logout\r"
        ": no such file or directory
```

(I modified the value)

Comment: I updated my answer; please let me know if you continue to have issues.

Comment: On another note: I think this is typo: `prompt="[$acc@$server ~]$ "`. You either meant `prompt="[acc@$server ~]$ "` or         `prompt="[$account@$server ~]$ "`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `while`, not `for`, to parse files in Bash. Use a "redirect" to treat a file as standard input and read one line at a time.

```
while read server; do
  ...
done < $fic_serv
```

Your major problem is Expect interprets your `"`s as "end of script". Escape them, as in `\"`, or use `{}`, as in:

```
 expect -c "
        spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $account@$server.$suffix
        expect {Password: }
        send {$passwd\r}
        expect $prompt
        send {logout\r}
        "
```

Comment: But single-quote `'` has no meaning to Expect.  The equivalent is `{ }`, e.g. use 
`expect  {Password: }`

Comment: Hello 
I corrected it and it works now but still have a problem:
It doesn't seem to send password because no connection is done....
It goes directly to next ssh without displaying anything
Any idea about this trouble?

Comment: Use the `-d`iagnostic flag to debug exactly what's happening.

Comment: expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "[acc@server ~]$ "? no

it seems prompt variable is not transmitted through expect...

Answer (score 1):

If you have 400 servers to manage, I strongly recommend you use `ansible`.

You could just put the list of hosts into a file, let's call it `inventory`, and run the following command:

```
ansible -i inventory -m shell -a "id acc" all
```

Answer (score 0):

Using here-docs in the shell to embed code for another language is usually better than quoting hell, and sharing variables through the environment is easier and safer than parameter expansion:

```
export account passwd
while IFS= read -r server; do
    export prompt="[$acc@$server ~]$ "
    export host="$server.$suffix"
    expect << 'END_EXPECT'
        spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $env(account)@$env(host)
        expect  "Password: "
        send "$env(passwd)\r"
        expect $env(prompt)
        send "logout\r"
        expect eof
END_EXPECT
done < "$fic_serv"
```

As shown, I like to indent the heredoc to make it more obvious.

And depending on the error message or login prompt, there can be more logic to indicate that the account name and/or password are incorrect.

Comment: Seems to have a problem:
    expect: option requires an argument -- 'c'
    usage: expect [-div] [-c cmds] [[-f] cmdfile] [args]
    expect: option requires an argument -- 'c'
    usage: expect [-div] [-c cmds] [[-f] cmdfile] [args]
    expect: option requires an argument -- 'c'
    usage: expect [-div] [-c cmds] [[-f] cmdfile] [args]

Comment: I keep forgetting this: when reading commands from stdin, don't use -c

Comment: I'm not familiar with heredoc but it works!!
Thanks

Comment: It's shell construct. It's a special form of input redirection: you're basically redirecting from a file, except the file contents are inside the script. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents